# How to tell when Visual Studio key bindings or settings change?

Tags: visual-studio, vsix

From a Visual Studio extension, is there any way to tell that settings have been changed? I'm particularly interested in knowing when the key bindings have changed, although I'd settle for knowing the settings have changed after showing the options dialog.